# Issues with apache poi and swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am using apache POI library in order to change automatically a word file using java code. I have create an JtextField in which I import values to program and I tried to change the bookmarks of the word file with those given values. When I run my program I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/impl/CTPImpl$1BookmarkStartList
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTPImpl.getBookmarkStartList(Unknown Source)
at temp.DOCXTest.procParaList(DOCXTest.java:182)
at temp.DOCXTest.insertAtBookmark(DOCXTest.java:124)
at temp.testpea$event.actionPerformed(testpea.java:236)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
```

Any idea why those exceptions appeared? I am trying to change bookmarks in actionevent of textfield. Is there any issue with apache poi and swing library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next to the core Apache POI library you also need **poi-ooxml**.
This contains the XWPF packages which are required to open and manipulate
Microsoft Word files.

poi 3.11

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

poi-ooxml 3.11

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
       <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

ooxml-schemas 1.1

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```